# How to call update() method of in Angular 2 Perfect Scrollbar wrapper?

Tags: angular, scrollbar, perfect

I try to implement Perfect Scrollbar to my Angular 2 Application and use Angular 2 Perfect Scrollbar wrapper: https://github.com/zefoy/angular2-perfect-scrollbar
If i have large content at application start moment my scrollbar appears and works normally.
But if my content grows dynamically - scrollbar is not appear.
I think I have to call the update() method of Scrollbar object when content is added. How can i call Perfect Scrollbar methods from Angular 2 components?

Answer (score 4):

One can do it like this. First, insert perfect-scrollbar selector and give it a custom ID inside an HTML template:

```
<perfect-scrollbar #scroll1 class="container">
   <div class="dynamic-content"></div>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

Then in the typescript file refer to this element using defined ID and assign its type:

```
@ViewChild('scroll1') scroll1: PerfectScrollbarComponent;
```

Finally, call *update()* method through *directiveRef* property of the Perfect Scrollbar component inside whatever method in the same file:

```
yourMethod() {
   this.scroll1.directiveRef.update();
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Worked for me.