# Angular 4 update perfect scrollbar

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, perfect-scrollbar

I'm using angular2-perfect-scrollbar in my angular4 app. I initialized it and it works fine but when I delete an item from my list the scrollbar is not updated and overflows the actual content

I tried to update it as it is described here
[How to call update() method of in Angular 2 Perfect Scrollbar wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903837/how-to-call-update-method-of-in-angular-2-perfect-scrollbar-wrapper) but it did not works.

I'm using the perfect scrollbar directive in a tbody element (the display attribute is set to block.) but that should not be the problem.

```
            <tbody #tableContent *ngIf ="users" [perfect-scrollbar]>
```

It is included in my module

```
import { PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface, PerfectScrollbarModule } from 'angular2-perfect-scrollbar';

@NgModule({ imports: [ SharedLibsModule, PerfectScrollbarModule.forRoot(PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG) ],
```

I my component I include the container like this:

```
    @ViewChild('tableContent') tableContent: PerfectScrollbarDirective;
```

An I call the update like this:

```
private onSuccess(data, headers) {
    this.tableContent.update();
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

@Edit: The scrollbar is updated and it works fine if I try to scroll on the table or If I resize the browser window.

Comment: have you find solution. Please post if found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working fine if I read the PerfectScrollbarDirective like this:

```
@ViewChild('tableContent', {read: PerfectScrollbarDirective}) tableContent: PerfectScrollbarDirective;
```

Then call the `this.tableContent.update();`